# QAOA for Binary Optimization

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, optimization, qaoa

I have reduced an optimization problem to a Binary Integer Linear Programming model as follows:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2^n-1} f(C_j)x_j \rightarrow \max$$

$$\text{subject to} \sum_{j=1}^{2^n-1} S_{i,j}x_j=1\,\, \text{for}\,\, i=1,2,....,n\\\\$$

$$x_j \in \{0,1\}\ \ \ \text{for}\ j=1,2,.....,(2^n-1).$$
By referring the [Ising Hamiltonian for different NP-Hard Problems](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2014.00005/full)
: I have computed the Hamiltonian for the above problem as follows:
$$H_A = \alpha \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left [ 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}S_{ji}x_i \right ]^2 \text{where}\  \alpha>0\ \text{is a constant}$$
$$H_B = -\beta \sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}f(C_i)x_i\ \text{with}\ \beta\ll\alpha.$$
Here we have to replace the binary values $x_i$ by the eigenstates of Pauli $Z$ operator applied on the *i* th qubit:

$x_i = 0$ implies $z_i = 1$

$x_i = 1$ implies $z_i = -1$

Basis $|0\rangle$ is an eigenstate of Pauli $Z$ with respective eigenvalue +1 and basis $|1\rangle$ is an eigenstate of Pauli $Z$ with an eigenvalue -1.

Therefore, we replace $x_i$ by $(1-z_i)/2$ .

I have this setup, and I find it difficult to implement the QAOA circuit to solve this problem. Also explain the way QAOA would work in this setting. Can somebody help me with this ?

I even studied QAOA to come up with the following circuit formulation:

$$H(t) = tbH_A + (1-t)H_B\\
U(t_0) = U(H_A,\beta_0)U(H_B,\gamma_0).$$

Iteratively we have;

$$U = U(H_A,\beta_0)U(H_B,\gamma_0)\dots U(H_B,\beta_p)U(H_B,\gamma_p).$$

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome to QCSE! Consider writing equations using Latex instead of using images. To do so, just enclose Latex code between \$ for inline equations and \$\$ for equations centered in their own line

Comment: Thanks !! Just did.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04769. Here, you can find a way how to translate your Hamiltonian to a unitary operators which can be implemented on a quantum computer.